# How To Find The Line Having nth length

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, apache-pig

Sample file:

```
this
is
a
sample
file
with
several
lines
of
varying
length
```

Used AWK to find the count as (count of occurence [for] length of word):

```
  1 1
  2 2
  3 4
  1 5
  2 6
  2 7
```

Please Suggest how to find the line which contains nth length.

**Ex:- 'is' having length 2 at line 2, please suggest how to find the lines having same length.**

Comment: It seems that the problem is not hard, but I don't get the requirement clearly.  Can you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: 'is' having length 2 at line 2,? Can you explain more on this? Is the output data for your sample file?

Comment: just check it inside the awk for equality

Answer (score 4):

One simple way to get lines with a specific length is to use egrep with regex:

```
egrep -n '^.{2}$' your-sample-file.txt
2:is
9:of
```

In the regex `"^.{2}$" the "."` (period) represents any character, even space, and `"2"` represents how many times `"."` should repeat. `"^"` and `"$"` represent the beginning and the end of a line. The `"-n"` parameter asks egrep to retrieve the line number.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v "len=2" 'length($0)==len{print}'
```

per @dood suggestion

```
awk -v "len=2" 'length($0)==len'
```

works as well and is fundamentally a `grep` on length which is pretty neat.

edit, re interpreting the question based on the list of numbers shown,
returning result in no particular order

```
awk '{a[length($0)]++}END{for(i in a)print i, a[i]}' bar
4 3
5 1
6 2
7 2
1 1
2 2
```

Comment: What do you need '{print}' for?

Comment: to print the line when the test for length matches  but I dont think this is the answer OP is looking for. I think they want a histogram of lengths.

Comment: by default print without arguments outputs the line it is on

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do without '{print}' statement, try it out.

Comment: @dood  you are correct, it is not the `print` it does not need, it is the body `{}`. I don't think I ever wrote an awk without a body before, it is effectively a grep. thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what u want.

```
  cat test.sh
    this
    is
    a
    sample
    file
    with
    several
    lines
    of
    varying
    length


awk -v "len=2" -F "\n" '{if ((length($0))==len) print "line " NR " length is " len}' test.sh
line 2 length is 2
line 9 length is 2
```

Comment: it worked but when there is space at any line it's not working please suggest

Comment: Now it will work. by default awk takes space as field separator. now i have made it to new line

Comment: you are/were  finding the length of the _last_ word in a line $0 will be the entire line

Comment: @tomc yup before it was last word but now $NF is complete line as separator is new line.
but thanks for reminding me. i have replaced $NF with $0

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -C -nle 'print "$. $_" if length == 2' < file
2 is
9 of

$ grep -n '^.\{2\}$' file
2:is
9:of

$ awk '/^.{2}$/ { print NR, $0}' file
2 is
9 of
```

With GNU sed you can print the line numbers on separate lines in the output:

```
$ sed -ne '/^.\{2\}$/ !d ; =; p' file
2
is
9
of
```

where `!d` deletes the line, if it doesn't match the pattern, `=` adds the line number with a trailing newline into the pattern space, and `p` prints the current pattern space. It looks like there is no built-in option to not print trailing newlines for `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming finding is just counting the line that comply the criteria of length and not returning an array of each available count (like your second data sample):

```
awk -v "Length=4" -F '[[:alnum:]]' 'NF == ( Length + 1)' YourFile

# or in tinyline "optimized"
# 5 = 4 (len) + 1

awk -F '[^\001]' 'NF==5' YourFile
```

Tip:

- `{print $0}` is the default action of a pattern/condition matching, in this case `NF == ( Length + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

display the line

```
awk -v "Length=4" -F '[[:alnum:]]' 'NF == ( Length + 1) { print $0 }' YourFile

# or in tinyline "optimized"
# 5 = 4 (len) + 1

awk -F '[^\001]' 'NF==5' YourFile
```

counting the line

```
awk -v "Length=4" -F '[[:alnum:]]' 'NF == ( Length + 1){Count++} END{ print Count}' YourFile
```

detail for each matching line

```
awk -v "Length=4" -F '[[:alnum:]]' 'NF == ( Length + 1){ print NR ":" $0}' YourFile
```

Tip:

- `{print $0}` is the default action of a pattern/condition matching, in this case `NF == ( Length + 1)`

(e)grep is, for this purpose, the fastest and best solution especially on huge file

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk  ' {k=length($0); a[k]=a[k] FS $0} 
     END {for(k in a) print k ":" a[k]}' file | 
  sort -n

1: a
2: is of
4: this file with
5: lines
6: sample length
7: several varying
```

you can easily add the line numbers...

```
$ awk ' {k=length($0); a[k]=a[k] FS $0 "(" NR ")"} 
    END {for(k in a) print k":"  a[k]}' file | 
  sort -n

1: a(3)
2: is(2) of(9)
4: this(1) file(5) with(6)
5: lines(8)
6: sample(4) length(11)
7: several(7) varying(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Apache Pig**. Generate row numbers by using rank.Filter the resulting relation by comparing the row number with the size of the record.

```
A = LOAD 'sample.txt' as (line:chararray)
B = rank A;
C = FILTER B BY ($0 == SIZE(line))
DUMP C;
```